# PyMysql error : Packet Sequence Number Wrong - got 1 expected 0

Tags: python, mysql, error-handling, pymysql

I saw in the stackoverflow and another coding example sites which this topics discussed.
But I cannot find any mature solution about it, is anyone fix this error ?

Error Message:

```
ERROR:root:Can't connect to to MySQL server with error: (pymysql.err.InternalError) Packet sequence number wrong - got 1 expected 0
ERROR:root:Can't connect to to MySQL server with error: (pymysql.err.InternalError) Packet sequence number wrong - got 1 expected 0
ERROR:root:Can't connect to to MySQL server with error: (pymysql.err.InternalError) Packet sequence number wrong - got 1 expected 0
ERROR:root:Can't connect to to MySQL server with error: (pymysql.err.InternalError) Packet sequence number wrong - got 1 expected 0
ERROR:root:Can't connect to to MySQL server with error: (pymysql.err.InternalError) Packet sequence number wrong - got 1 expected 0
ERROR:root:Can't connect to to MySQL server with error: (pymysql.err.InternalError) Packet sequence number wrong - got 1 expected 0
```

Connection settings is like below:

```
   "mysql+pymysql://{u}:{p}@{s}/{d}?charset=utf8".format(
                u=creds['username'],
                p=creds['password'],
                s=creds['host'],
                d=creds['dbname']
            ),
            pool_recycle=3500,
            echo=False,
            pool_pre_ping=True,
            pool_size=2,
            max_overflow=5
        )
```

Comment: pymysql doesn't seem to be developed any more, how about using the mysql connector instead

Comment: @nbk this does not seem to be true - latest version was released June 2023.

Comment: The comment is from march  2022 and at that time there where no updates for some p Ng  time, and I wrote it seems

Answer (score 5):

Following this [link](https://pypi.org/project/pymysql-pool/) I got:

> While using pymysql with python multithreading, generally we will face
> the questions:
>
> It can't share a connection created by main thread with all
> sub-threads. It will result in the following error:
> pymysql.err.InternalError: Packet sequence number wrong - got 0
> expected 1 If we make every sub-thread to create a connection and
> close it when this sub-thread ends that's workable but obviously lead
> to high cost on establishing connections with MySQL.

It seems they have developed other library to solve this:PyMySQL Connection Pool (same link)

Answer (score 2):

**1. Install pymysql-pool**

```
pip3 install pymysql-pool
```

**2. Import it on code**

```
import pymysql

import pymysqlpool
```

**3. Config it on code startup**

```
config={'host':'localhost', 'user':'{dbuser}', 'password':'{dbpass}', 'database':'{dbname}', 'autocommit':True}


pool1 = pymysqlpool.ConnectionPool(size=2, maxsize=3, pre_create_num=2, name='pool1', **config)
```

**4. On each query**

```
con1 = pool1.get_connection()

gcu = con1.cursor()

gcu.execute("SELECT ....")

myresult = gcu.fetchall()

con1.close()
```

**5. On each commit:**

```
con1 = pool1.get_connection()

gcu = con1.cursor()

sql = "update ..."

gcu.execute(sql)

con1.commit()

con1.close()
```

So, this code can **work with no interrupt forever** with the **minimum** system *resources*...

Comment: does not solve the problem